# how do I create a virtual jquery filetree?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I would like to create something like this using ruby on rails.

Im not tied to jquery but it seems like this his what I want:
http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/projects/js/jquery/fileTree/demo/

The issue is I want to build the tree not based on a file system, but based on ruby code which pulls info from various models. In other words, my files are stored in the database under various models and I want to query them and decide to build how to build the file tree.

thanks
Joel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FileTree plugin is independent from server-side scripts and offers the possibility to create [custom connectors to feed it with data](http://abeautifulsite.net/blog/2008/03/jquery-file-tree/#custom_connectors):

> You can create a custom connector script to extend the functionality of the file tree. The easiest way to do this is probably by modifying one of the scripts supplied in the download. If you want to start from scratch, your script should accept one POST variable (dir) and output an unsorted list in the following format: [...]

this should be very easy to connect with a simple Ruby script.